# Why are my org tables no longer exporting?

Tags: org-mode

Today I tried to export an org table by issuing `M-x org-table-export <RET> table.csv <RET> <RET>`. To my surprise, I received the error message

```
Symbol's function definition is void: org-export-create-backend
```

I believe this is happening because of my recent upgrade to org-mode version 8.3.1 from version 7. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Elsewhere, you'd [mentioned](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16815/how-can-i-export-many-org-documents-to-ascii#comment24887_16820) you tried installing both the git and ELPA versions of Org.

So that's most likely the problem. You might want to clean up and reinstall Org:

### Cleanup

#### 1. Remove the git version of org

You can use [`make clean-install`](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-build-system.html#outline-container-sec-3-7) to remove an org installation from git. If you customized your install location, make sure to use the same settings.

#### 2. Remove the ELPA version of Org.

In `list-packages`, move point over the Org package, press `d` to mark it for deletion, then press `x` to execute the deletion.

### Reinstall Org

Pick your favorite way of installing Org, and do that. Either the git version or ELPA version is fine, but the git version is more [bleeding-edge](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#keeping-current-with-Org-mode-development). You shouldn't need incredibly new Org for most things, but it will have slightly more features and bugfixes.

Comment: After completing (1) and (2), issuing `M-x org-version` returns `Org-mode version 7.9.3f`. This version exports tables fine. Reinstalling org through ELPA then upgrades me to version 8.3.1 and the problem arises again. In fact, this version seems to effect a few other things, like table functions and table importing. Could this be a problem with 8.3.1 itself?

Comment: And thanks for taking the time to look this!

Comment: After a lot of googling, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988092/emacs-org-mode-export-markdown/22990257 which ended up working!

Comment: What exactly did work for you?